# mysql comparing two set of unique id field which is of varchar datatype and seperated by comma

Tags: mysql, sql

A table has a field in which i store many indexed id's of another table seperated by comma like this

> Table sam
>
> id - name - gid
>
> 2  - sami - 23,12,43

the gid's are references to another table which

now from the client side i am sending some gids to the server for comparison

so i need to match those with that of table sam

the gids from the client side might be in any order like 12,43,23 or 12,43,57

and i want to match any occurrence like if from the client side the gids are 12,40,50 and if any field in the table has 12 then it should be matched.

is it possible with sql or do we have to go for some more steps with more queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `substring_index`, and `find_in_set`

```
mysql> select find_in_set(substring_index('12,40,50', ',', 1), '12,13,14');
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| find_in_set(substring_index('12,40,50', ',', 1), '12,13,14') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            1 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select find_in_set(substring_index('12,40,50', ',', 1), '121,13,14');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| find_in_set(substring_index('12,40,50', ',', 1), '121,13,14') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             0 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**BUT** you should consider to normalize your data structure, your way ist too unnormalized.

Comment: Yeah. but in this case how to normalize? just references to such concepts would do good.

Comment: split each of the elements become an individual row

Comment: Booo this does not work at all. It only checks against the 1st number of `'12,40,50'`, which is `12`

Answer (score 1):

Hey use regular expression in ur query

```
$string = '12,50,56';
SELECT * from tablename where gids REGEXP [[:<:]].$string.[[:>:]]
```

This will match the exact pattern

To match any field that will contain 12 use [[:<:]]

Sanil

Comment: IT is working well. But i want or operation too. like ... gid will have 12,43 and i want it to return true because atlease 12 is present.  in your case it is working like and operator. i want both ways.